# How do I build a dynamic column name using psycopg2?

Tags: python, sql, dynamic, psycopg2

I need to dynamically build a query that - given a supplied variable, e.g. 20 or 19 - can select from columns for the right year, e.g.

```
    `SELECT products20 FROM some_table;`
```

or

```
    `SELECT products19 FROM some_table;`
```

I've tried hard to find any examples of this and haven't been successful. I've also tried many approaches to this with sql.Identifier or Composable. The closest I can get is:

```
    `SELECT products%(yr)s FROM some_table;`
```

But I end up with single quotes added, e.g.

```
    `SELECT products'19' FROM some_table;`
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to have an extra table for products and a relationship.

Comment: I’m just and end user of the database with no say in its structure and these are adjacent columns. My example is just meant to be abstract.

Comment: The suggested "already answered" question, does not, in fact, answer this at all.